# How can I create a list with the money flow of each transaction inside a block?

Tags: python, json, blockchain

I'm working on a json file to analyse the data of a block chain. I'm trying to find for each transaction the amount of money moved by summing all the outputs unless those that have the same address of the inputs.  This is the piece of code:

```
moneymoved = []
for tr in transactions:
    money = 0
    for outp in tr['out']:
      w = 0
      while w < len(e['inputs']):    
        if outp['addr'] != tr['inputs'][w]['prev_out']['addr']:
           money = money + outp['value']
           moneymoved.append(money)
           w = w + 1 
        else:
            w = w + 1
```

I think that "moneymoved.append" is in the wrong position, as It should execute after the calcolous of all outputs inside each transaction. How can I proceed?

Comment: I agree with you.  The `append` should be after the `while` loop.  You can move `w = w + 1` out of the `if` block as well since you do that in either case after the `if`.  Beyond that, I don't think there's enough information here for the community to be of much more help.  Even if we could help, what you're talking about is the basic task of programming.  You have to run your program over and over, watch what it's doing (you should be using a good visual debugger), and expand it line by line by matching code to what you want the code to do.  This is the learning you have todo.

Comment: Thank you Steve, I have already tried to move out the append and also the w = w + 1, but the problem is that the list money moved is of higher size than the number of transactions. Inputs and out are two keys which I want to compare in their adressess in order to know if the output value must be included or not inside the list money moved. My aim is to create a list which contain, in each position, the moneymoved in the reference transaction.